# ALTER stored procedure (with no changes) causes it to run 20x slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've been doing some speed tests on a stored procedure that does a bulk insert. It takes some JSON as a parameter, creates a table variable, weeds out any duplicates in the table variable from what's already in the destination table, and then copies the data from the table variable to the destination table.

In running these tests, I was seeing some wildly different speed results that were driving me nuts. They made no sense. I finally pinned down the issue and I'm able to reproduce it consistently.

Here's the process:

1. Delete all data from the destination table
2. Run the stored procedure and pass in a JSON record of 50,000 rows
3. It executes in about 1.5 seconds.
4. Repeat the process. This time it has existing data it needs to parse looking for duplicates. Same results. Less than 2 seconds
5. Repeat step 4 N times always with the same results.
6. Run an ALTER on the SP without having made ANY changes to the SP itself
7. Repeat step 4. This time it takes 30-40 seconds!!!
8. Delete the data in the destination table, repeat all the steps, same results.

I've been reading up on parameter sniffing, trying things like converting the passed in parameters to local parameters, and adding `WITH RECOMPILE`, but so far, the results are all the same.

If this were to happen in prod, it would be unacceptable. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit long for a comment.

SQL Server caches the plans for queries in a stored procedure when they are first run.  In your case, the first run has an empty table so the query plan is based on an empty table.  That seems to be a good query plan for your problem.

When you alter the stored procedure, you do have one effect:  it forgets the cached query plan.  So a new plan is generated, one that uses the current size of the table.

For whatever reason, this second query plan is much worse than the first.  I don't know why.  Usually the problem is the other way around (the query plan on the empty table is the worse one).

I would suggest that you figure out how to get the query to have the right plan when there is data and to recompile the code in the stored procedure each time it is run.  That might be overkill, but it adds just a little overhead.

Comment: ok ok. That makes sense!  How does one recompile the code in the stored procedure each time it is run?

Comment: You add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the code.  But, in your case, the recompiling seems to be the issue.  You may also need hints so the query chooses the best plan.